# const_iterator type of a container of const types

Tags: c++, stl, containers

If I compile the code below:

```
#include <list>

using iter_t = std::list<const unsigned>::const_iterator;

int main(int, char**) {
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following compile error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
             from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/allocator.h:46,
             from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/list:61,
             from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of 'class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<const unsigned int>':
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/allocator.h:92:11:   required from 'class std::allocator<const unsigned int>'
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_list.h:315:9:   required from 'class std::_List_base<const unsigned int, std::allocator<const unsigned int> >'
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_list.h:447:11:   required from 'class std::list<const unsigned int>'
main.cpp:3:41:   required from here
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/ext/new_allocator.h:93:7: error: 'const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = const unsigned int; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = const unsigned int*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = const unsigned int&]' cannot be overloaded
   address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
   ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/4.9.2/ext/new_allocator.h:89:7: error: with '_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = const unsigned int; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = const unsigned int*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = const unsigned int&]'
   address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
   ^
```

I get roughly the same error message if I change the container type from `std::list` to `std::vector`, `std::deque` or `std::forward_list`. If I change the template argument from `const unsigned` to `unsigned` it compiles fine.

What's going on here? I can't see why it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual C++ 2015 gives the clarifying diagnostic

> **”** The C++ Standard forbids containers of `const` elements because `allocator<const T>` is ill-formed.

<del>As I understand it, this is because an allocator's `allocate` method returns a pointer to an array of uninitialized `T` items, and if `T` is `const` then these items can never be initialized.</del>

<del>I can't find any explicit statement that `allocator<const T>` is ill-formed, so it is presumably a consequence of the semantics.</del>

As Dieter Lücking notes [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519915/const-iterator-type-of-a-container-of-const-types/36519961?noredirect=1#comment60645619_36519961), there is a direct clash for `const` type `T` between the two member functions that provide address of a `reference` and `const_reference`, because these are equal when the type is `const`.

Comment: Visual C++ might be on to something :); I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685257/why-cant-you-put-a-const-object-into-a-stl-container).

Comment: The clash are the two member functions `address` of a reference and const_reference (which are equal if the type is constant)

Comment: @DieterLücking: Thanks! Updating... Done.