# C++ how to cast std::vector<int> to const std::vector<const int>?

Tags: c++

I want to cast a `std::vector<int>` to `const std::vector<const int>`, it seems that it can not be automatically casted. So I have some questions:

1. I can easily cast `std::vector<int>` to `const std::vector<int>`, why is that?
2. If I want to cast to `const std::vecor<cosnt int>`, how should I do that? I've tried const_cast but doesn't work

Comment: `std::vector<const int>` won't compile, you can't have const elements.

Comment: You can't have a vector containing a `const` type. You can't have any STL container with `const` element type. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685257/why-cant-you-put-a-const-object-into-a-stl-container

Comment: I wonder what kind of "easy" cast would allow what you report in your first bullet.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  If you want to make sure the data in the vector is not mutated then you can use its `const_iterator`'s.

Answer (score 6):

> If I want to cast to `const std::vecor<cosnt int>`, how should I do that? I've tried `const_cast` but doesn't work

Short answer: Don't.

When you make a `std::vector<int>` const, as-in `const std::vector<int>`, the contents themselves become implicitly `const` as well. In other words, if you write something like this, you won't be able to modify the elements:

```
const std::vector<int> values{1,2,3,4,5};

//Nope
//values.emplace_back(6);

//Also Nope
//values[3] = 5;

//Still nope
//values.erase(values.begin() + 1, values.begin() + 3);

//Nuh-uh
//std::vector<int> & mutable_values = values;

//This, however, is okay.
std::vector<int> const& immutable_values = values;

//Same restrictions though
//immutable_values[2] = 6;
//immutable_values.emplace_back(7);

//This is fine
std::vector<int> copy_of_values = values;

//But that's because you made a copy
copy_of_values.emplace_back(6);
assert(copy_of_values.size() != values.size());
assert(copy_of_values != values);
```

This is why STL containers like `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::map`, and so on, prohibit the use of `const` members within their template parameter lists: because making the container itself `const` also makes its contents `const`, which is a stated contract of the design of these containers. Some "containers" don't have this property, like Smart Pointers, which is why you'll sometimes see stuff like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(42);
std::shared_ptr<const int> non_modifying_ptr = ptr;
```

Which is part of the core functionality of reference-counted pointers.

This, incidentally, is all part of making sure your code is "const-correct", and I strongly advise you do a google search on that very subject and learn about what it is, and how to properly apply it in your code to make your code safer and more performant.

Comment: I'd add that if you declared `const std::vector<int>` and you wanted to perform a simple `push_back()` you'd have to `const_cast`. But declaring an object as const and then const_casting it many times is pretty useless...

Comment: @AlbertoMiola That would be undefined behavior, actually. It's perfectly legal to `const_cast` away the `const`-ness of an object if you ***know*** that the object wasn't originally declared `const`, but if the object *was* declared `const`, then it's UB, and unsafe.

Comment: I was referring to the parameter passing way of declaring an array const, since the OP seemed to be confused about it. I should have specified I was referring to that!