# Correct behaviour for std::vector<T>::value_type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

After scratching my head at some errors in some template code that used `std::vector::value_type` I tracked it down to the following. Is this correct behavior according to the standard, or is this a problem with MSVC 2012 CTP?

```
typedef std::vector<int>::value_type       t1;
typedef std::vector<int const>::value_type t2;

static_assert(!std::is_same<t1, t2>::value, "hmmm");
```

The above assertion fails.

Comment: IMO I would expect `std::vector` (and the other containers) to `std::remove_const` for their `value_type`, but this appears to show that they don't.  Huh.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No. As per the Standard, `value_type` is just `T`. It doesn't remove const-ness.

Comment: The question is : is `std::vector<int const>` allowed?

Comment: What do g++ and clang (and any other c++ compiler) have to say about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `value_type` of a `std::vector<T>` is `T` (§23.3.6.1).

The value of `is_same` takes cv qualifiers into account (§20.9.6).

In your case that means checking `std::is_same<int, int const>`, which is supposed to fail.

Which in turn means that the behavior you observed is wrong according to the standard. It seems that MSVC is dropping the cv qualifiers for value_type:

```
std::vector<const int>::value_type val = 5;
val = 10;
```

This compiles on MSVC2008 but fails with gcc 4.4.

You should probably file a bug report with Microsoft.

**Edit:** Nawaz's comment above got me thinking. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759350/embarassing-c-question-regarding-const?lq=1) `const int` is indeed *not* allowed as a a value_type in C++03!
<strike>It seems though that it is in C++11.</strike>. While it's not explicitly forbidden in C++11 for vectors, it is forbidden for allocators (§17.6.3.5), which in turn makes it illegal for vectors as well.

In any case, MSVC's behavior of silently dropping the `const` seems wrong here.

Comment: I feel empty after reading this... That's an awesome investigation work here!

Comment: Although your expectations make sense to me, AFAIK, `std::vector<const int>` is **not** standardized. Therefore, Microsoft might implement it as an **extension** (which GCC doesn't) stripping the `const` from `const int`.

Comment: I guess you could argue it's indeed undefined behavior by the standard and therefore Microsoft is technically right to do as they please. I still wonder though whether the current behavior is intentional or it's just in there because nobody complained about it before.

Comment: Props for citing the part of the Standard that prevents this, which the _de facto_ canonical answer, [Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t) did not do.

Answer (score 3):

GCC 4.7.2, for instance, fails to compile the OP code even before it reaches the `static_assert`.

The problem is that standard containers (e.g. `std::vector`) were not designed to hold `const T` because they depend on allocators and the standard in [allocator.requirements] only defines the allocator behavior for non-const, non-reference object types.

As far as I understand, this means that using `std::vector<const int>` yields undefined behaviour. Therefore, both compilers are right!

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c0x-allow-vectorconst-t) question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6955332/1137388) answer and Howard Hinnant's comment on it, which I quote the first sencence:

> Bottom line: We didn't design containers to hold `const T`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me `std::vector<const int>` is not allowed: According to the standard T shall be `CopyInsertable` and `const int` isn't.

See *Sequence container requirements* at 23.2.3 Sequence containers [sequence.reqmts] in the draft [N3485](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/N3485.pdf).

The OP code fails to compile with both gcc 4.7 and icc 13.0 at the line

`typedef std::vector<int const>::value_type t2;`

Apparently, the MSVC discards the const qualifier.