# Cast vector<T> to vector<const T>

Tags: c++, constants

I have a member variable of type `vector<T>` (where is T is a custom class, but it could be int as well.)
I have a function from which I want to return a pointer to this vector, but I don't want the caller to be able to change the vector or it's items. So I want the return type to be `const vector<const T>*`

None of the casting methods I tried worked. The compiler keeps complaining that T is not compatible with const T.

Here's some code that demonstrates the gist of what I'm trying to do;

```
vector<int> a;
const vector<const int>* b = (const vector<const int>* ) (&a);
```

This code doesn't compile for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not return const reference instead?

Comment: [vector-and-const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102244/vector-and-const)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you have a `const vector<int>` you cannot modify the container, nor can you modify any of the elements in the container.  You don't need a `const vector<const int>` to achieve those semantics.

Comment: I should have tested that before I asked. I tested it now, and it works like you described.
Thank you.

Comment: but what if I have vector<const string>? It makes sense most of the time to create such vectors.

Comment: @user3111311 No.

Answer (score 17):

On why a `vector<T>` cannot be correctly converted to a `vector<const T>` even if `T` can be converted to `const T`

This is a common recurring problem in programming whether it is with constness or inheritance (a container of derived object cannot be converted to a container of base objects, even if the contained elements themselves can). The problem is that element by element each one of them can be converted, but the container itself cannot without breaking the type system.

If you were allowed to do `vector< const T > &vr = my_vector_of_T`, then you would be allowed to add elements through `vr`, and those elements would be constant by definition. But at the same time those same elements would be aliased in `my_vector_of_T` as non-const elements and could be modified through that interface, breaking constness in the typesystem.

In the particular case of a `vector<int>` being converted to a `vector<const int>`, chances are that you would not notice really weird effects --besides adding an element to a `vector<const int>` and seeing how the *constant* element changes in time, but still remember that given two related types `T1` and `T2` for which a relation exists, in most cases trying to apply the same relationship to containers of `T1` and `T2` will break the type system.

Comment: +1 for explaining why altering the container can cause trouble even if the references in the container are const.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to James's answer about how to do it you should note that `const int` is not a valid type to put into any standard container since it is not assignable.

Answer (score 1):

you can force conversion like this:

```
b = reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<const int>*>(&a);
```

but I do not think you should do this, since it is not guaranteed to work, only to compile

Comment: Since the OP used a c-style cast this is actually effectively what they tried to do.  A c-style cast will do a reinterpret cast when the types are unrelated and vector<int> is unrelated to vector<const int> or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler decides to block this. However, we know this is safe so maybe we can fool it:

```
const vector<const int>* b = (const vector<const int>* )(void *)(&a);
```

Comment: Well, it's not safe. The type `std::vector<const int>` is invalid because `std::vector<T>` requires that T is assignable and `const int` isn't.

Comment: The funny thing is I used a compiler that would compile this until you tried to write to the vector then you get a really obscure compiler error.

Comment: "we know this is safe" - haha, wow! "safe" is never, not once, an appropriate thing to say about `reinterpret_cast` to anything except `[un/signed] char const *`. Everything else is implementation-defined if you're _lucky_ and are willing to write brittle non-portable code. Besides, (A) `T const` is not a valid element type, and (B) even if it were, the Standard need not put the 2 instantiations' member variables in the same order, so even if `reinterpret_cast` did reinterpret object representation on your compiler, it's folly to assume compatible members live at equivalent offsets within both