# Casting vector<int> to const vector<const int>

Tags: c++, casting, constants

How can I cast `vector<int>` to const `vector<const int>`?

I've tried `static_cast<const vector<const int>>(array)` and using the value without a cast. Neither compiled.

Comment: You cannot. `vector<int>` and `vector<const int>` are completely different types. Pass a `span` or `array_view` instead.

Comment: @nwp then how would I implement my cache? Would plain old `const vector<int>` work?

Comment: To provide `const ` access to a `std::vector<int>` use a `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`

Comment: `*static_cast<vector<const int>*>(&array)` may work

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Doesn't work unfortunately `static_cast from 'vector<int> *' to 'vector<const int> *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed`

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Nope. `std::vector<int>` is completely unrelated to `std::vector<const int>`

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868485/cast-vectort-to-vectorconst-t --

Comment: @chema989 I'm casting the other way around

Comment: `std::vector<const int>` isn't valid anyway since elements must be assignable.

Comment: @chema989 In fact this looks like a dupe of the question you linked to.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC There's no need to ever make a `vector<const T>`, and in fact it's usually not even valid.

Comment: I realized there is an inherent problem with my caching implementation. I'll edit that part out and leave this for others to see.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Of course that won't work. The types are unrelated. And don't think of using `reinterpret_cast`! That's UB waiting to happen (or if you're _lucky_, implementation-defined behaviour, which is no more useful IMHO). Even if you're tempted to say 'well, they'll really have the same member layout, so it's fine' - it's really not.

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry, from a python background it looks like "Why wouldn't it work?"

Comment: @SebastianRedl Even if it seems to work, the Standard doesn't seem to guarantee it's valid: [Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t), to which the answer from a very reliable source appears to be a distinct _no_. The real fleshing-out is in the comments, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast a `std::vector<int>` to `const std::vector<const int>`.

Besides, it does not make sense to use a `std::vector<const int>` at all. It doesn't give you any more safety than a `const std::vector<int>`.

Not only that, C++ does not allow construction of `std::vector<const T>`. See [Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t) for more info.

Comment: ...can a `vector` even _have_ `const`-qualified element type? It's never worked for me when I tried in the dim and distant past, and it doesn't work for me now with `int const`.

Comment: @underscore_d, g++ does not allow creating a variable with `std::vector<const int>`. I don't know whether there is anything in the standard that prohibits such a variable.

Comment: I thought maybe it was to do with non-availability of copy/move ctors in the element types for which I tried it before, meaning reallocations and sorts and etc would need to use `operator=`, which obviously isn't `const`... but `int` has those, which torpedoes my theory. Sigh - off to the Standard I go.

Comment: @underscore_d a `const int` doesn't have `operator=` available to it.

Comment: To clarify, I was referring to it having the ctors, not assignment.

Comment: [Does C++11 allow vector<const T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t), to which the answer from a very reliable source appears to be a distinct _no_. The real fleshing-out is in the comments, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the type of the elements of the vector, but you can change the type of the vector to `const std::vector<int>` which will prevent making changes to the vector.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    const std::vector<int>& v2 = v1;
    v2.push_back(4); // Causes an error
    v2[0] = 4; // Causes an error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although it doesn't solve my caching problem, I'll leave it here because it might help others

Comment: This makes the _container_ const, but I'm guessing that by trying to use the disallowed concept of 'a container with `const` _elements_', OP hoped to be able to add to/reallocate the container (non-`const`) while not being able to alter elements after construction (`const`). One might assume this were possible post-C++11 as the compiler could use copy and move constructors for elements instead of assignment - but in reality, containers were never intended to have `const` elements - and currently, an incompatible default allocator prevents that anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906