# cast std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> to std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const T>>

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, smart-pointers

I have three class members:

```
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object> > getObjects();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Object> > getObjects() const;

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object> > m_objects;
```

I'm getting a compiler error when I return `m_objects` in the `const` version of `getObjects()`, because `m_objects` does not match the return type (`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Object>>`).

In my workaround, I first reconstruct the object vector locally by iterating  and then return the local vector, but is there a more optimized way of handling this scenario?

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const Object> > objects;
for (auto & object: m_objects)
{
    objects.push_back(object);
}
return objects;
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. Those are unrelated types.

Comment: Ok, but I suppose the content of the local variable wont be copied but moved in the case of assigning a variable to getObjects(), for example auto objects = objectManager->getObject();, where objectManager is a const pointer.

Comment: One solution is to not return a `vector` and instead make the class itself [into a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container). Note that this may betray the class's intent and overcomplicate things.

Comment: How about simply `return {m_objects.begin(), m_objects.end()};`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast from `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const T>>`, even `reinterpret_cast` would yield undefined behavior. For details, the related question [`cast vector<T> to vector<const T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2868485/783510) could help.

Creating a copy is the best that you can do. But, as Frank pointed out, it can be written more concise as `return {m_objects.begin(), m_objects.end()}`. That also avoids some unnecessary allocations, as the size of the final container is immediately known (in contrast to the `push_back` approach).