# Passing vector of void pointers by reference when a vector of specific type is expected

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, void-pointers

Consider the following scenario:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int a;
        A(int _a) : a(_a) {}
};

void Get(std::vector<A*>& vec)
{
    A* a1 = new A(5);
    A* a2 = new A(50);
    A* a3 = new A(500);
    vec.push_back(a1);
    vec.push_back(a2);
    vec.push_back(a3);
}

int main()
{
    // Scenario 1
    auto vec = std::vector<A*>();
    Get(vec);
    for(auto* v : vec)
        std::cout << v->a << std::endl;

    // Scenario 2: 
    auto vecvoid = std::vector<void*>();
    vecvoid.assign(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for(auto* v : vecvoid)
        std::cout << static_cast<A*>(v)->a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In *Scenario 2*, is it possible to pass `vecvoid` directly to `Get()` (without overloading/modifying `Get()`) instead of using the two-step approach (function call followed by call to `vector::assign()`) as shown above?

Comment: Why are you trying to work with `vector<void*>`?

Comment: @UKMonkey Legacy codebase

Comment: Related/approx dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122858/why-is-a-vector-of-pointers-not-castable-to-a-const-vector-of-const-pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, it's not possible.
`std::vector<A*>` and `std::vector<void*>` are unrelated types.

Consider what could happen if it were possible:

```
void G(std::vector<A*>& vec)
{
    *vec[0] = A(7);
}

// ...
int x = 0;
std::vector<void*> v = { &x };
G(v); // Oops.
```

Answer (score 1):

It could probably work on common compilers with a `reinterpret_cast` but it clearly invokes Undefined Behaviour because it is **not** a valid use of `reinterpret_cast`:

```
Get(reinterpret_cast<std::vector<A*>&>(vecvoid));
```

I have just tested it with CLang 3.4 and it gives expected results without even a warning. It is not really a surprise because the assembly code generated for pushing a pointer into a vector is the same whatever the type of pointer. But you will have to control the generated assembly to make sure...

TL/DR: Please do not do that! It is simply not C++ code because as you  have been told in other answers a `vector<void *>` and a `vector<A *>` are completely different types..

Answer (score 0):

> In Scenario 2, is it possible to pass vecvoid directly to Get()[?]

No it is not.

Although `A*` is convertible to `void*`, `std::vector<A*>` is a completely different type than `std::vector<void*>`. An alternative would be:

```
struct A {};
A a1, a2;
auto veca = std::vector<A*>{&a1, &a2};

auto vecvoid = std::vector<void*>{begin(veca), end(veca)};
```