# Can the argument of a converting constructor be implicitly converted?

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion

Right now I'm working on a project where convertibility between two classes (A and B) is highly desirable. I've created a function myFunc() that takes an object of class A as its argument, and I've passed it an object of class B.

The reason I expected this to work is that B can be implicitly converted to an integer, and A can be implicitly constructed with an integer. I expected these two processes to occur so that an object of class B would implicitly be converted to an object of class A. This was not the case.

When I try to pass in an object of class B to myFunc(), I get the error: `error: could not convert 'b' from 'B' to 'A'`.

Interestingly, however, I can pass in an object of class B that I explicitly cast to an integer, or an explicitly constructed object of class A which takes an object of class B as its argument. It seems that only one implicit process (whether it be a converting constructor or an implicit conversion) can happen in a single line. Why is this the case? Is there any way to get around this issue?

I know that a simple solution would be to create a constructor in A that takes an object of class B as its argument, or to create an operator in B that converts an object of class B to an object of class A. For my purposes, however, these solutions should not be used unless absolutely necessary.

I'm still learning C++ (I've come over from Java). Hopefully the code below will clarify what I'm talking about. Thank you for your feedback in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

// objects of class A can be (implicitly) constructed with an int
struct A {
    A(int) {}
};

// objects of class B can be (implicitly) converted to an int
struct B {
    B(int) {}
    operator int() { return 0; }
};

// myFunc takes an object of class A
void myFunc(A)
{ }

// why can't myFunc convert the argument b like the following: B -> int -> A?
int main()
{
    B b(5);

    // These work:
    myFunc((int) b);
    myFunc(A(b));

    // This does not:
    myFunc(b);
}
```

Note: The code above should compile properly until `myFunc(b);` is commented out.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, and an easy mistake to make since you're new, but please don't use what's called C-style casting (or perhaps Java-style casting, considering where you come from) like `(int) b`. It's often seen as a "red flag" that there's something bad going on, perhaps silencing a compiler warning (about behavior that could lead to *undefined behavior*) or even error messages that shouldn't be silenced. In this case you should use [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In many context a C style cast is OK: when the construct can only be a `static_cast`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a *conversion sequence* in C++. To get from one type to another, there can be only a limited number of steps. Importantly, there can be at most one step from each of the possible categories. E.g. you can have at most one numeric promotion ( e.g. `short` to `long`.). Importantly for your example, there can be at most one *user-defined conversion*. This is **either** a *converting constructor* (`Foo::Foo(Bar)`) **or** a *conversion function* (`Bar::operator Foo`). Your example needs both.

Comment: That doesn't sound right; are you saying that there can be at most one conversion to const?

Comment: @curiousguy: How would you create a `const const T`? Adding cv-qualifications is idempotent; doing it twice does not give you an extra-const object. And while you **can** have `T const* const*`, you can't convert a `T**` to `T const* const*`.

Comment: You can't? Why not?

Comment: @curiousguy: Basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102244/vector-and-const/2102415#2102415

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: @curiousguy: Same reason: You could store a `T const*` via the `T const* const*`, and then read it back as a `T*` via the `T**`.

Comment: Of course you could use a complicated and indirect way to use a cast. I don't see how that's a language problem.